# Custome Button Borders and Galleries

Tags: javascript, html, css, border, gallery

I am a beginner at coding and am self taught. However, I am finding things I am unsure of how to do but are probably really easy to achive but I need some help please.

I have been looking at this website: https://megans.co.uk/

My first question is:- for all the buttons how to they achieve the custom border with the 2 x circles in the corner?

My second question:- For the hero image slider, what would be the code to link the buttons to the image slider?

Sorry if this is very basic.

Thanks
S

Comment: You should have a loot at https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/ or the respective documentation for your browser of choice. You can look into the code and see how they did it

Comment: If you use the Dev Tools, you can see, that it has nothing to do with borders itself. They used [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and ::after Pseudo Elements and styled them accordingly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the circle at border of buttons use before and after selector.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <style>
    div {
      padding: 50px;
      background: #ccc;
    }
    .border {
      position: relative;
      border: 1px solid #ffffff;
      background-color: transparent;
      padding: 20px;
      color: #000;
    }
    .border::after,
    .border::before {
      transition: all 500ms;
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 6px;
      height: 6px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .border::after {
      bottom: -3px;
      right: -3px;
    }
    .border::before {
      top: -3px;
      left: -3px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="border"> Book now</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and for slider button i think they are using jQuery with trigger like

```
    $('.left-button').click(function() {
        MySliderClass.trigger("prev.owl.carousel");
    })
    $('.right-button').click(function() {
        MySliderClass.trigger("next.owl.carousel");
    })
```